# Thunderbird stopped working

Tags: thunderbird

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and Thunderbird has stopped working. I can no longer send or receive emails in Thunderbird. My settings and ports are all correct. This issue occurred from one day to the next and nothing on my computer has changed. 
Has anyone got a way to solve this?

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: No error message. It just times out after about 90 seconds without getting any emails.